# How to replace img tag with pitcure tag in summernote?

Tags: jquery, ajax, summernote, ajaxform

I am trying to replace img tag with picture tag in editor.

Editor adding url like : `<img src="http://localhost/news/uploads/large/6dBUlfZZBW.webp">` With the following code on upload success :

```
success: function(url) {
   var image = $('<img>').attr('src','http://' +url);
   $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
}
```

**And I want to change it to picture tag like this** :

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 400px)" srcset="uploads/large/JS60y3eMKG.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="uploads/medium/JS60y3eMKG.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source media="(max-width: 200px)" srcset="uploads/small/JS60y3eMKG.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="uploads/small/JS60y3eMKG.webp" alt="test">
</picture>
```

**Note:** all images has same names but different folders, and I am using v8.20 here is the [minified version](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.20/summernote-lite.min.js) if anyone wanna take a look :

Here is the [complete setup demo](https://codepen.io/dlkkn/pen/abqZaor)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a picture tag straight from the string, that is obvously unsafe.

```
const picture = $(`<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 400px)" srcset="uploads/large/JS60y3eMKG.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="uploads/medium/JS60y3eMKG.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source media="(max-width: 200px)" srcset="uploads/small/JS60y3eMKG.webp" type="image/webp">
    <img src="uploads/small/JS60y3eMKG.webp" alt="test">
</picture>`)
```

And just insert it like you did with an image

`$('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", picture[0])`

It would be safer to split them into components.

```
const picture = $('<picture>')
const source1 = $('<source>').attr('srcset', url).attr('media', size)
const source2 = $('<source>').attr('srcset', url).attr('media', size)
const source3 = $('<source>').attr('srcset', url).attr('media', size)
const img = $('<img>').attr('src', url)
picture.append(source1, source2, source3, img)
$('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", picture[0])
```

Now you can iterate through your ajax response and dynamically create and add new source's to a picture.

Comment: Looks good, but it doesnt insert image into editor. I tried allmost same example with var picture

Comment: @Dlk that worked for me in my playground, could you re-create your problem in a code-sandbox online type environment so i could see what exactly is happening?

Comment: Here is the senbox and codepen is added in to question https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-jennings-yi9leb sendbox doesnt upload files so it will not work properly, will just display images uploaded by core js not return uploaded image.

Comment: @Dlk https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-brook-os0cnp check this out, works for me here, inserts a simple picture, it feels like there is something else in your code that is a problem

Comment: You need to test it in localhost with php upload process budd, yours is just a manuel pasted image, summernote decode images, unless they are not uploaded. I want to upload image and insert with picture tag.

Answer (score 0):

###### This is a three part problem,

First is to find a way to insert custom markup stuff, then to update image to upload functionality and finally update image from link functionality.

Here is a working demo, https://codepen.io/shramee/pen/jOZVbxV?editors=0010

#### The solution

##### 1. Function to insert markup

```js
function addImageToSummerNote( imageUrl ) {
  var HTMLstring =
        '<picture>' +
        '<source media="(min-width: 400px)" srcset="' + imageUrl + '" type="image/webp">' +
        '<source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="' + imageUrl + '" type="image/webp">' +
        '<source media="(max-width: 200px)" srcset="' + imageUrl + '" type="image/webp">' +
        '<img src="' + imageUrl + '" alt="test">' +
        '</picture>';
  $( '#summernote' ).summernote( 'pasteHTML', HTMLstring );
}
```

##### 2. Hooking in the function for uploads

```
function sendFile( imageUrl ) {
  ...
  $.ajax( {
    ...
    success: function( url ) {
      addImageToSummerNote( url );
    }
  } );
}
```

##### 3. Overwriting insert image from link

```
$("#summernote").summernote({
  ...
  onImageLinkInsert: function (url) {
    addImageToSummerNote( url );
  },
  ...
});
```